# Qt5 -static x64 and linking nightmares

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt5

I'm trying to compile Qt5 64 bit under Windows 7 64 bit with the -static option.

Here's what I did:

1) Downloaded the Qt sources and extracted them into a C:\Qt5\5.0src directory
2) Followed all the steps here http://www.geometrian.com/programming/tutorials/setup_Qt.txt to set up the environment variables and .conf files to build statically
3) Launched configure with

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-msvc2010 -nomake tests -nomake examples -opengl desktop
```

The opengl desktop parameter was needed because there's a bug with -no-opengl and I can't compile angle.

Finally launched jom.exe -j5 /p

and I got this error which I don't know how to solve

```
moc_qwindowsinputcontext.cpp
        lib /NOLOGO  /OUT:..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindows.lib @C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\qwindows.lib.3796.29562.jom
        cd qtsvg\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.0src\qtbase\bin\qmake C:\Qt\5.0src\qtsvg\qtsvg.pro -o Makefile ) && C:\Qt\5.0src\j
om.exe -f Makefile
        cd src\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.0src\qtbase\bin\qmake C:\Qt\5.0src\qtsvg\src\src.pro -o Makefile ) && C:\Qt\5.0src\j
om.exe -f Makefile
        cd svg\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.0src\qtbase\bin\qmake C:\Qt\5.0src\qtsvg\src\svg\svg.pro -o Makefile ) && C:\Qt\5.0s
rc\jom.exe -f Makefile
        C:\Qt\5.0src\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug all
Error: dependent 'C:\Qt\5.0src\qtbase\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib' does not exist.
jom: C:\Qt\5.0src\qtsvg\src\svg\Makefile [debug-all] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.0src\qtsvg\src\Makefile [sub-svg-make_first-ordered] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.0src\qtsvg\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.0src\Makefile [module-qtsvg-make_first] Error 2
```

It seems that "Qt5Widgetsd.lib" doesn't exist... why is that? Why hasn't it been built?

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could not solve it but I discovered that -no-opengl has problems with Qt5 so I switched to Qt4 and solved my problem